# Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Failed to read marionette port

Tags: java, firefox, ubuntu-22.04, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium with Java and Firefox but I am getting the below issue.

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Failed to read marionette port
```

- ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- Geckodriver version: 0.330
- Firefox version: 116.0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is bug in firefox binary installed using apt/snap, I faced same issue when I installed firefox from apt package respository. I solved this by downloading firefox from [official mozilla source](https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/116.0.3/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-116.0.3.tar.bz2) and symlinked binary to /usr/bin/firefox/

First remove firefox from you system.

```
apt remove firefox
```

Download firefox from official source. (You may need to replace download URL)

```
wget https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/116.0.3/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-116.0.3.tar.bz2
```

Extract downloaded archive to location you want. I am using opt to extract archive.

```
tar -xf firefox-116.0.3.tar.bz2 --directory /opt/
```

Then symlink firefox binary to /usr/bin

```
ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```